# One computer on network slow - but it wasn't always?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, speedtest

Let me start by saying that I have a pretty good understanding of my computer and OS so I've covered the basics here. I'll give you all the details and hopefully I can get some good feedback.

I'm running a Dell less than a year old with an i7, win7, 1TB, 8GB, etc. It's a nice machine. A few days ago my HDD crashed and went out. I called Dell, got the HDD replaced and now here we are. I have a fresh windows install with all the "proper" drivers but my network speed is now garbage. I have tried changing the frequency of the antennas, updating the drivers, checking other computers, etc but with no luck. My wifes computer pulls 45Mb down on my network and my work computer gets 50Mb down. The computer giving me issues is only getting between 2Mb-10Mb down depending on when I test it. All three computers from the same spot on my couch, less than 5 feet from the router, in a controlled test. I haven't plugged it in but when I check the connection properties, I have an excellent connection with 130Mbs-144Bbs at all times. I've even gone so far as to uninstall the driver and use the driver from Dell's support website. It's really frustrating!

My thought is that there's something physically wrong with my card but before I have to send my machine out to Dell and be without it for XX weeks, I was just curious if anyone had any insight here or if there's something obvious I might be missing?

I don't know if it matters but my wireless card is an Intel Centrino Adanced N-2230. I've googled the card itself but it seems like to common problems have more to do with dropping the whole connections as opposed to just speed issues.

I'm at a loss! Please help!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you compared performance between a wired and wireless connection? Have you checked how often you're losing packets?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have not yet checked a wired connection but only because I don't have a wire available at the moment. As far as packets go, I'm not familiar with the concept. Could you elaborate a little more? Thanks!

Comment: How exactly are you testing it?   Are you connecting to the internet and downloading the same exact file from the same website on each computer?   Is this local transfer?   when you say Mb I hope you are keeping in mind that Mb (megabit) and MB (megabyte) are very different in terms of value when talking about network speed by a factor of 8.   Best way to test internet/wan speeds would be to download the same file from the same source on different computers.     Try the 100mb test file from cachefly http://cachefly.cachefly.net/100mb.test

Comment: The first thing to check here would be the drivers since this is a fresh Windows install. Did you download and install the drivers for your wireless card?

Comment: I was using speedtest.net to test. I'll try this way now. Thanks

Comment: In command prompt, run `ping -n 100 $routerIPaddress` (replace `$routerIPaddress` with your router's IP) - it will take a few to many minutes to complete, depending on how good your connection is. When it finishes, it will print `Ping statistics for $routerIPaddress:` and a line describing the results of the test, one of which will be your packet loss rate. Packet loss rate indicates how often data fails to transmit, so if you're pinging your router, the packet loss rate indicates how often data your computer is sending to your router isn't making it there).

Comment: I did download the drivers - right from the dell site for my machine and configuration.